# Play sound and change play icon to stop icon on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to play a sound when I click in a button with code below but its not working.

And I also want that the play icon change for stop while the sound is playing.

But its not working, do you see where the issue is?

http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/351/

jQuery:

```
var playBtn = document.getElementById('play');

var playSound = function() {
    audio.play();
};

playBtn.addEventListener('click', playSound, false);
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){audio.pause()}, false);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to get `audio` element. By the way, id must be unique in your html.

According to [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp):

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value
>   must be unique within the HTML document).

```
var playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
var stopbtn = document.getElementById('stop');

var playSound = function () {
    audio.play();
};

var stopSound = function () {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
};


playBtn.addEventListener('click', playSound, false);

stopbtn.addEventListener('click', stopSound, false);
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/804jeg82/354/)

```js
var playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
var stopbtn = document.getElementById('stop');

var playSound = function () {
    audio.play();
};

var stopSound = function () {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
};


playBtn.addEventListener('click', playSound, false);

stopbtn.addEventListener('click', stopSound, false);
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="sounds"> <a href="#" class="btn">
      Mountain 1
      <audio id="audio" src="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP3/Nero_SmartTrax/NeroSmartTrax_test4_MPEG2_Mono_CBR_40kbps_24000Hz.mp3" preload="auto" ></audio>    
    
   </a>

    <br> <i id="play" class="fa fa-play"></i>

    <br> <i id="stop" class="fa fa-stop"></i>

</div>
```

Comment: @Oscar Does it fix your problem?

Comment: Thanks! And to change the icon for a stop while is playing and then if the stop button is clicked the music stops? You know how to do this?

Comment: @Oscar Is that helpful?